# How to get call modal('closeModal') from authentication.html

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, ui-form, knockout, loginpopup

## Question

How do I get access to the underlying `modal object from a UiClass object`?

This Magento Stackexchange answer shows how to call `closeModal` on a modal window:

> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/173972/89285

> `$("#popup-modal").modal("closeModal");`

### Information

The following files apply to my question:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web
  -- js/view/authentication.js        
  -- template/authentication.html
```

#### Explanation and Issue

I have overridden and customized the checkout template and js files, and loaded correctly in the custom theme.

I want to add a link like this, with `data-bind="click: doGuestCheckout"` (which I define inside `authentication.js`

```
        doGuestCheckout: function () {
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
// Here I want to call the modal('closeModal') method from the UiClass object once I have done all the other pre-processing.
        }
```

> Debugging inside `doGuestCheckout` (or the built-in `login` function):
> `this` returns `UiClass` type

This is inside `authentication.html` template.  This calls `doGuestCheckout` correctly, but I want to be able to call `closeModal` afterwards as explained above.

```
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <a class="action action-register primary" href="#" data-bind="click: doGuestCheckout">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Checkout as Guest'"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I do not know how to find the underlying `jquery modal` object from this UiClass instance, so currently I made a button `data-role="closeBtn"` which then automatically calls the `modal.js closeBtn` function. This functionality is exactly as the authentication Login popup close button (and this 'custom button').

```
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button class="action primary" data-role="closeBtn" type="button">
                <span>Checkout as Guest</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, this is not ideal, as I cannot implement additional features before 'closing the modal form'.

In other words, when you click the authentication popup **close button**, eventually `Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal.js::closeModal` gets called when I put a breakpoint.

> I want to be able to access the modal object from the `UiClass inside authentication.js functions` *so that I am able to close the ui form after I am done*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access to the modal class simply by selecting the element with jquery

The binding of the modal in authentication.html is on the element `".block-authentication"`, so a simple `$(".block-authentication").modal("closeModal")` should work.

**EDIT from OP:**

Thanks for this!

This was the way I ended up doing it, but at the time of writing the original question couldn't find the relevant selectors.  What complicated things more was that the theme used has **two popup modals with the same selector `.block-authentication`** and they would counteract behaviour when hiding.

I ended up giving the relevant popups IDS where they were defined, for this relevant related to question:

```
Magento_Checkout::web/template/authentication.html

<div id="block-authentication-checkout-customer-modal-popup-content"
        class="block-authentication block-authentication-modal-popup-content"
```

This ensures that custom behaviour while still showing for the relevant popups don't break.